# scanf("%d", &<variable>); returns 1

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to make a console app in C that calculates the travel time between cities. The problem is that my `scanSlut` method keeps returning 1. ("slut" in danish = end in english, and since I am danish, I give variable names danish names. This is also to prevent calling other variables in libraries, which are all in english.)

```
    printf("Indtast destinationsstationsnummer:\n");
    slut = scanSlut(start);
    if(slut > 15 || slut < 1) {
        do {
            printf("Du har indtastet en ugyldig ankomststation. Indtast venligst en gyldig station\n");
            slut = scanSlut(start);
        } while (slut > 15 ||slut < 1);
    }

int scanSlut(int start) {
    int slut, i;
    for(i=1; stationer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(i!= start) {
            printf("#%d: %s\n",i,stationer[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("slut = %d\n", slut);
    slut = scanf("%d", &slut);
    printf("slut = %d\n", slut);
    return slut;
}
```

The first `printf("slut = %d\n", slut);` returns random numbers (which is logical since the variable contains garbage until it's set), but the second `printf` keeps writing 1, even if I press some random number.
I have got a `scanStart()` method too, which does what I want it too:

```
int scanStart() {
int start, i;
for(i=1; stationer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("#%d: %s\n",i,stationer[i]);
}
scanf("%d",&start);
return start;
}
```

I have tried build, rebuild, restart IDE, and still all I get is 1. any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
slut = scanf("%d", &slut);
```

`scanf` returns the number of input items assigned. Change it to:

```
scanf("%d", &slut);
```

(See `man scanf` for more information regarding `scanf`).

Comment: Or even better save the return value of scanf to a separate variable and check it to make sure your scanf actually suceeded